# How to declare pointers/references to template class member types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pointers, reference

I hope the title is not too far off. Consider the following piece of code:

```
template<class C>
struct Wrapper {
  using type = C;
};

int main()
{
  Wrapper<int>::type *a;
  Wrapper<int*>::type b;
  int i;
  Wrapper<int>::type &c = i;
  Wrapper<int&>::type d = i;
}
```

Here, `*` and `&` can either go into the template argument or can be attached to the variable name. While I think both ways of declaring have the same effect, this is just my question:

Are the different ways of declaring pointers/references equivalent or are there situations in which one of them is preferred over the other for whatever reasons (e.g. safer, compiles faster, better style, ...)?

Comment: In _your_ case it might not make a difference, in other cases it does.

Comment: Which would those be?

Comment: When the type is used in the class, for example.

Answer (score 3):

> Are the different ways of declaring pointers/references equivalent or are there situations in which one of them is preferred over the other for whatever reasons (e.g. safer, compiles faster, better style, ...)?

Not *preferred*, but they can yield actually different results. Think of *partial specialization*:

```
template <typename T>
struct Resource_wrapper {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct Resource_wrapper<T*> {
   using type = std::unique_ptr<T>;
};
```

Here, it makes a great difference between writing `Resource_wrapper<int>::type*` and `Resource_wrapper<int*>::type`.

Or consider `std::unique_ptr<>`, which also uses partial specialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr; // smart pointer managing integer array
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr[5]; // array of five integer smart pointers
```